# snapsvg .drag() attr definitions

Tags: snap.svg

I'm just starting with snap.svg. The `element.drag()` function provides a set of defaults if no parameters are passed, otherwise you have to define your own `onmove`, `onstart` and `onend` functions.

The parameters for `onmove(dx,dx,x,y,event)` can be used in your implementation of `onmove` to move the element.

If I create a group of elements, the default `g.drag()` allows the group to move but I can't figure out what to put in my own `onmove` to make the group move.

`this.attr({cx: posx , cy: posy});` works for a `.circle`. What are the equivalent `x`,`y` for a `.group`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I just tested:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

Snap.load("draw.svg", function(f) {
g = f.select("g");
s.append(g);

g.cx = 40;
g.cy = 140;
g.ox = 0;
g.oy = 0;

g.drag(dragging, startDrag, function(evt) {
            console.log("dropped at: "+ evt.x + ", " + evt.y);
        });


});

startDrag = function(posx, posy) {
  this.ox = posx - this.cx;
  this.oy = posy - this.cy;
}

dragging = function(dx, dy, posx, posy) {
  this.cx = posx - this.ox;
  this.cy = posy - this.oy;
  t = 't' + this.cx + ',' + this.cy;
  this.transform(t);
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, here you are creating the cx,cy,ox,oy var's on the g object.  The example on snapsvp.io site seem to have the cx,cy already defined for circles, rects but not for groups? A movement can be achieved by just using this.attr(cx: 100, cy:100) on a circle.  It seems that groups have to handled differently using the method you have outlined.

Comment: Groups should use transforms really for simplicity as in the example. Its fine to use cx/cy if just dragging a circle, but assuming you want to do more, I would get used to using transforms and groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [transform](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.transform) method on group elements.

```
dragging = function(dx, dy, posX, poxY, event){
    this.transform("translate("+posX+","+posY+")");
}
```